# Birkhoff conjecture about integrable billiards

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, open-problems, billiards

There is a conjecture by Birkhoff which claims that for a simple closed $C^2$ plane curve $C$, if the billiard ball map is integrable then the curve is an ellipse.

Integrability here might be formulated as follows: there exists a neighbourhood of $C$ in the interior $Int(C)$ that is foliated by caustics (caustics being curves that are everywhere tangent to a given trajectory of the billiard ball).

I would be interested to know the current status (and progresses, if there are) of this conjecture.

Comment: Currently there is no Wikipedia article on the Birkhoff conjecture. Would someone here care to remedy this deficiency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't heard of any recent breakthroughs. The strongest result that I know is due to  [Misha Bialy](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02572397):

> **Theorem.** If almost every phase point of the billiard ball map in a strictly convex billiard table belongs to an invariant circle, then the billiard table is a disc.

Stronger results are available for an outer version of the Birkhoff conjecture. Tabachnikov
proved that if the outer billiard map around a plane oval is algebraically integrable then the oval is an ellipse ([article](http://pjm.math.berkeley.edu/pjm/2008/235-1/pjm-v235-n1-p07-s.pdf), [arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.0255)).

Comment: Then what one should think about the following paper?

http://nyjm.albany.edu/j/1997/3-2.html

The author claims that he has solved the conjecture for $C^\infty$ curves. 

Comment: Unfortunately most people I talked to don't believe Amiran's proof is correct.  I don't know what exactly is wrong with it.

Answer (score 8):

For a recent progress see http://arxiv.org/pdf/1412.2853.pdf
a local version of this conjecture is proven.

Answer (score 4):

I'm no expert, but [according to Tabachnikov](http://books.google.fr/books?id=g8PdXL4ST4YC&lpg=PR7&ots=H2DaDdVh4z&lr&pg=PA95#v=onepage&q=birkhoff&f=false) the conjecture was still open as of 2005, while [Delshams and Ramirez-Ros have a local](http://upcommons.upc.edu/e-prints/bitstream/2117/1189/1/9503delsh.pdf) result (i.e. the conjecture is true when considering symmetric entire perturbations). Probably Mathscinet would help more.

Comment: (By the way, hello Damien!)

Answer (score 1):

I think has recently obtained partial results on this conjecture ([On polynomially integrable Birkhoff billiards on surfaces of constant curvature, JEMS 2021](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.04030))